# Display Value in textbox in Window application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in Window application. I have two forms form1 and form2. From1 has a textbox and form2 has a combobox. Now I want to display combox selected item of form2 into textbox of form1 when i close form2.So I have defied a static class (marketclass) and assigned selected value to statik variable. Beow is my code of form2.

```
    private void cboMarkets_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         marketclass.nAlgoproperty = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMarket.SelectedValue);
         this.Close();
    }
```

Now Below id is my code of form1.

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          

        if (marketclass.nAlgoproperty > 0)
        {
            textbox1.text = marketclass.nAlgoproperty;
       }
}
```

But is not working. So how can I achieve this thing.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Try to be specific.

Comment: Combox seleted value of form2 is not displaying in textbox of form1 when i select combox value and close form2.

Comment: Where do you call the `form2` in `form1`, you should do the assignment after you have launched the `form2` which will be then setting the value

Comment: Is `marketclass` an instance or a class? remember that statics should be accessed via Class name, not instance;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show Form2 via ShowDialog(), then retrieve the value:

```
// ... in Form1 ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog(); // code stops here until "f2" is closed
textbox1.text = marketclass.nAlgoproperty;
```

Comment: Yes, `ShowDialog()` is preferable over `Show()` - too much room for further confusion with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

**In general**

This type of problem is well-solved using the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern.

This looks like WinForms, which does not exactly have excellent support for MVC.  However, in spite of that, you can certainly implement the MVC pattern.

For a good getting started article I suggest you have a look at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp

**Specific to this Question**

You are attempting to achieve a similar result using static variables.  The problem is quite possibly the timing of when you change the backing static variable's value, and when you look for changes.

```
textbox1.text = marketclass.nAlgoproperty;
```

is called when Form1 is loaded.  It could be that Form1 was indeed loaded before Form2's checkbox handler updated the value in `marketclass`.

Even if that is not the case today, that exemplifies the type of issue that you will run into with the pattern you are now using.

The MVC pattern solves this type of timing issue by binding one or more controls to a backing variable such that, if a UI element changes the value, the value is updated and all other bound UI elements are also updated.  Conversely, if the value changes (say because it was loaded from the database) all bound UI elements are automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setted ComboBox's ValueMember property? if it is not, well, you should or if your using the combobox displayed text as value, you have to use SelectedText property instead:

```
private void cboMarkets_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     marketclass.nAlgoproperty = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMarket.SelectedText);
     this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the assignment `textbox1.Text = marketclass.nAlgoproperty` in `Form1`'s constructor (i.e. *before* `Form2` assigns a value to `marketclass.nAlgoroperty`).

Setting aside the "best" way to do this, you can just perform the assignment after the call in `Form1` that shows `Form2` (i.e. once `Form2` closes).

```
form2.Show();
textbox1.Text = marketclass.nAlgoproperty;
```

That should do it.  Once you get that working, consider a better way to do it - e.g. the [MVC and Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477508/1810429) design patterns.

Comment: yes I know but when i open form2, select combobox value and close form2 then i want to display that value in textbox. How can I perform the assignment after the call in Form1 that shows Form2

Comment: How can I perform the assignment after the call in Form1 that shows Form2. I dont know tha way. can u plz give me example?

Answer (score 0):

I found the short code, and put the value of display!

```
int widht = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;//l
int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;//h

textbox1.text ="Widht -> " +widht + " : Height ->" +height
```

You welcome!!

Comment: this is not related with question, there are no forms, nor nothing; what are you meaning?